# Windows 10 Startup Programs Not Launching

Tags: windows-10, boot, windows-registry

Ok, I am at wit's end. For any user (new or existing) on one particular system, the programs in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` will not run. The programs in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` **do** seem to run as well as the two `Startup` folders.

All the apps I want running show as Enabled in the task manager Startup tab. They also appear in SysInternals AutoRuns checked.

The only out-of-the-ordinary thing I know of is that I installed and subsequently uninstalled [BootRacer](http://www.greatis.com/bootracer/).

Are there any registry settings or group policy settings that make those keys be ignored? Programs that keep them from processing?

Comment: So did you disable any programs from start up using BootRacer?

Comment: What were you trying to solve by installing BootRacer?

Comment: @Moab Possibly? However, after uninstallation, other programs that were installed that add a startup run key don't start up.

Comment: @music2myear I read about it in Maximum PC and wanted to see what it could do for boot times.

Comment: Is this a business computer or a personal computer?

Comment: i would reinstall bootracer and re enable those programs for startup.

Comment: @music2myear personal. Windows 10 Pro

Comment: @Moab Unless another, somewhat less painful solution presents itself, I will do just that.

Comment: For future reference, that is a **very** big *"only out-of-the-ordinary thing."*  The BootRacer web page specifically emphasizes that it is "[Quick and safe to disable programs](http://www.greatis.com/bootracer/)."  As a result, it is a fairly good bet to be the root cause of your problems.

Comment: You can use Autoruns a Microsoft application to temporarily or permanently disable startup items.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, Autoruns was already employed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BootRacer (and every speedy-boot program) works by flagging the boot entries in one of the many ways available to disable without removing them.

Because there are different methods of "disabling" these start-up entries, one program is not necessarily able to recognize that another program has disabled these entries.

When this is the case, the only solution is to either recognize HOW the items were disabled and then re-enable them manually, or use the program you used to disabled them to re-enable them.

Comment: I was able to re-install the program and DE-select "Enable Startup Control" and I have full abilities returned. If I'm feeling plucky in the future, I'll run sysmon or some such and find out the method it uses, but for now, it's unfortunate that the original attempt didn't put my system back to it's former state.

Comment: Indeed. While it's more of a power-user's utility and requires more knowledge on the part of the person running it, I stick with AutoRuns from Sysinternals for managing my startup entries.